# Recognizing my App in iTunes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am newbie to this forum. I have created my first iPhone application and created a distribution provision for executing in iPhone device.

While Sync my application to iPhone from iTunes, the icon of application is gud. After sometime the icon in iTunes gets changed into an square image. I have followed the following steps to create my iTunes artwork file.

**Steps followed**:

The iTunes artwork your testers see should be your application’s icon. This artwork must be a 512 x 512 JPEG or PNG file named iTunesArtwork. Note that the file must not have an extension.

After generating the file of your application’s icon, follow these steps to add it to your application:

Open your project in Xcode.
In the Groups & Files list, select the Resources group.
Choose Project > Add to Project, navigate to your iTunesArtwork file, and click Add.
In the dialog that appears, select the ”Copy items” option and click Add.
Note that the PNG or JPEG file is just 'iTunesArtwork', with no suffix.

Can anyone please suggest me how to make app icon in iTunes to be same as the one which is in my iPhone device ?

Thanks for any Help !

- Sathiya

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion of Chris Garrett, i have created the same png file for app icon in device and in iTunes. It looks fine when it is installed but when i restart the machine the the app icon in iTunes gets changed as square icon.

please suggest me to solve this !

Answer (score 0):

The app icon on your devices is a 57x57 png file located in your project directory.  The one you are uploading to iTunes Connect is a different 512x512 png file.  You'll want to make sure these two icons are basically the same (other than scaling effects).  It sounds like the icon in your project directory is different than the one you are uploading to iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is about Ad Hoc builds:

Make sure that there is no extension, you may need to Get Info and remove the ".jpg" extension there.

Also see msg 173247:
[How can I make my ad hoc iPhone application's icon show up in iTunes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173247/how-can-i-make-my-ad-hoc-iphone-applications-icon-show-up-in-itunes)

Comment: ya i have removed the .png extension. but the icon gets changed in itunes when the machine is restarted