# will the desktop appstore icon be appear only after approval?

Tags: iphone, itunesartwork

I am just going to submit my iphone application .

But I just have a doubt .

when I test my application with adhoc certificate the application icon come nicely in the device homescreen .

but I haven't got it for desktop app store (i.e iTunes).

I have read that I have to submit another 512x512 icon for the desktop icon .

Question :So this  512x512 icon will come in my itunes after I will upload through iTunes Connect and my application is approved ?

and will I have to include it in the binary or itunes connect uploading will make it work.

thanks .

Comment: This question may answer why you aren't seeing the icon in iTunes for your ad-hoc build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173247/how-can-i-make-my-ad-hoc-iphone-applications-icon-show-up-in-itunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the 57x57 icon as Icon.png in your application when you submit it to iTunes Connect.

You need only one icon in the application. You can submit a bigger version of the icon for your application in iTunes Connect, but you don't have to include it in your application.

Comment: so I have to include only 57x57 icon in the application build and 512x512 size the one for the desktop app store will be submitted to through the iTunes Connect , am I correct ?

Just confirming .