# How to Display the application icons in iTunes( Adhoc Distribution) in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, adhoc

In my application is in Adhoc distribution. I have drag the apps into the iTunes, it doesn't show the apps icon and it shows"UnKnown Genre". I know, once the apps icon is visible after submitting the application. But how to display the apps icon into the iTunes in the Adhoc distribution. So please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that....... its all handled by iTunes one as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved that issues by using this link, so please refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173247/how-can-i-make-my-ad-hoc-iphone-applications-icon-show-up-in-itunes)

THanks.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, you should accept the answer.